# Click the Submit button in a Form tag getting Viewstate url

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a form tag containing a input textbox, some checkboxes and the submit button.I need to check the checkbox and then click the button, I want to get these checked values in url as a querystring. Here is my code

```
<form method="get" id="CommonSearch" name="All-Search">
 <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("SearchTip")" class="form-control cust-txt">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sear" name="submit" value="@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Search")"> 

Listboxes..
</form>
```

But when I click the button I'm getting url:

```
http://localhost:355/product/?chbox=on&chbox=on&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2B3QbeXe9qnSJVHl5O1Ub47w%3D&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24cphcontainermiddle%24%5BSearch%5DShow+Countries_6%24ddlShowCountry=Afghanistan&select2=opt1&select2=opt&keyword=Test&submit=search
```

Anybody know why getting this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that because __ViewState is a hidden input that holds the viewstate for the page.

Viewstate is used by ASP.NET webforms to maintain state and data between postbacks (among other things).

There are two main ways that may fix this:

1) In the @Page directive at the top of the aspx file, you can set `EnableViewstate="False"`

2) Use a standard ASP.NET form and html or server controls (ones with runat="server" attributes) with a standard postback, and use `Response.Redirect("newurl")`.  You can build your new url in a loop based on the get scheme of `page.aspx?parameter=value&parameter2=value2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your form method is set to "`Get`", not the default "`Post`". There may be a reason why you've set it to "`Get`" but if you don't want the viewstate fields to be appended either remove the method="get" attribute or set it to "`post`".